# login to remote machine and run script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have one central machine and multiple remote machines. Configured passwordless connections to remote machines from central machine.

I have to login from central vm to remote vm's and execute script in remote vm's

Below is the example, what i am trying

Central Machine:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh root@remotemachine1
#run runscript.py in remotemachine1
ssh root@remotemachine2
#run runscript.py in remotemachine2
```

Remote Machine

```
python runscript.py
```

runscript.py

```
device = ["device1","device2","device3"]
for i, x enumerate(device):
    print "{}. {}".format(i+1, x)
select_device = raw_input("Choose Device: ")
print "You Selected Device {}".format(device[int(select_device) - 1])
do something
....
....
....
....

repeat = raw_input("Do you want to repeat? Y/N:")
do something
........
........
........
```

Someone help me how to login and run script in remote1 machine and exit from remote1 machine and run script in remote2 machine.

Comment: ansible? this looks like typical ansible usage secenairo

Comment: Not sure if PBS job scheduler can help.

Comment: Do you expect the user to provide inputs when the script is being executed on the remote machine?

Comment: Yes User will pass input during execution,

Comment: For scripting use `fabric`. For setting up hardware use `ansible` or similar.

Comment: ansible can execute in remote machine, I want to run script from remote machine, only remote machine has access to devices and not from central vm..

Comment: @triplee this is different question that duplicate question you have mentioned here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify how it's different from the nominated duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following command

```
ssh  $DEST_USER@$DEST_MACHINE "python -u path_to_your_script.py"
```

If your script is not there, please make sure you upload script using scp first and then execute above command.

```
device = ["device1","device2","device3"]
for i, x in enumerate(device):**
    print ("{}. {}".format(i+1, x))
select_device = raw_input("Choose Device: ")
print "You Selected Device {}".format(device[int(select_device) - 1])
```

Comment: But, how user will pass inputs during execution

Comment: -u option will take care of that. Please try out. It seems to be working fine across ssh

Comment: I can run it from central machine on remote machine and also provided inputs during remote execution.